Unable to scroll ion-content when closing a modal in front of a Capacitor Google Maps instance
For a project I have a map with markers. For the map I use @capacitor/google-maps. Upon clicking on a marker, a sheet modal (<ion-modal>) with information about the marker pops up. If the taps on the backdrop behind the modal, the sheet modal dismisses as it should. However if a user starts dragging right after (e.g. to drag the map) while the animation is still ongoing and ends the dragging after the modal has dismissed, the user is unable to scroll through pages in the rest of the application.
The issue only exists on Android, not on web. Perhaps it also happens on iOS, I haven't yet got the resources to test it on an Apple device.
A video can say more than a thousand words. I have provided a screen recording where the issue can be seen here
I tried a few things to address this issue:

I tried to put an overlay on the map while the map is dismissing, to no avail. It works but when the user is dragging after the overlay dismisses, the problem still happens.
I tried to unset touch event handlers for the map on page leave. I figured that maybe the map was handling touch events and stopping propagation before the app could handle the event. Unloading the map didn't fix the issue.
I tried to unload the map on page leave. I thought maybe the app still access the map for whatever reason. This also didn't work

None of these options have worked and I am quite clueless about this. I have produced a minimal reproducible example which can be accessed below. I couldn't provide the API key. The issue is still reproducible without the API key
GitHub repository

For the time being I have disabled the animation on the modal, which seems to fix it for now.
